# pls help : if isset not working in uploading multiple files

Tags: php, html

I tried to upload multiple files i used many scripts to upload it it's works fines but sometimes some files not upload i checked the problem

i have a file that contain images when i select all images i don't get any response when click submit

I just want it to say (hi) when i select all the files so that i can know it's reaching my code when upload.

```
<?php  /* and also checked by : */

if (isset($_POST['btnsubmit'])) {  
    echo "hi"; 
}

/* it's not working when i select all the images in once and click submit to check */

if(isset($_FILES['files']['name'])) {  
    echo "Hii"; 
}  // it's not working when i select all the files            
?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data"   >


    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Select Photo (one or multiple):</td>
            <td><input type="file" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" name="files[]" 
                multiple="multiple" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">Note: Supported image format: .jpeg, .jpg, .png, .gif</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" 
                value="Submit" id="btnsubmit"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Might want to show the code that receives the files. You mention `isset` but I don't see it.

Comment: I did add it now but i have some problem in putting the code because i didn't ask before in stackoverflow .

Comment: `print_r($_FILES)` check what r u getting after submission

Comment: i'm checking if there's submission or not by just printing (hi) and (hi) not showing .

Comment: i got Array ( )

Comment: P.S: Make sure to `exit;` inside your PHP, you don't want to send the same HTML back to the browser.

Comment: what ***exactly*** is your problem? -- what are you expecting ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thank u very much it solved the problem just by adding exit , can you put it as answer so i flag as solved , Thank you so much .

Comment: @Martin It's solved by Roko by adding exit; to the end of script , thanks martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's solved by adding

```
exit;
```

to php code .

thanks anyway .